# Learning to use Fetch for API

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning how to fetch data using online tutorials. I have this component working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Fetch API</h1>
<h2>The fetch() Method</h2>
<p id="demo">Fetch a file to change this text.</p>

<script>
fetch ("https://gbfs.citibikenyc.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json")
.then(x => x.text())
.then(y => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My next goal is to convert the data to json and then print the json data to the console (browser). I changed the script to be as follows, but this doesn't produce the result. Can someone suggest how I might fix my code to display the result as the json object?

```
<script>
fetch ("https://gbfs.citibikenyc.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json")
.then(file => file.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
</script>
```

Comment: "the result" — What does it do? What result do you expect?

Comment: "My next goal is to convert the data to json" — Nothing in the code you have even tries to do that. (`file.json()` parses the response (not a file) body  *from* JSON to a JS data structure)

Comment: Tried your code, it's working for me. I'm getting an array of JSON objects (stations). Can you specify the error or problem?